# How to Compile Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

```
linking miniruby.exe
win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____pioinfo
miniruby.exe : fatal error  LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.rel
```

This is the error in cmd while compiling the package using Development cmd for VS2015.
What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried http://rubyinstaller.org/?

Comment: have you tried linux?

Comment: No i need it on windows

Comment: rubyinsstaller doesn't have ruby-2.3.0 installer

Comment: what compiler you are using to compile it? Can you follow this guide? http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html

Comment: new ruby release are posted here on github: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error (minus some printed output differences) when trying to compile Ruby 2.5.1 on Windows using Visual Studio 2015 Express. I thought that all I needed to do was to add the `bin` directory to my `PATH`. So I did this and then tried building but I failed:

```
$> cd <path_to_ruby_download>
$> set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;%PATH%
$> win32\configure.bat
```

I was able to get past this problem thanks to some insight from [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/vs12-nmake-fatal-error-u1077-cl-return-code-0x2/234821) attempt. The main hint (from jules_a) is:

> **Looks like cl.exe cannot be found.** You should use vcvarsall.bat to
>   configure your path properly.

I tried searching for this `vcvarsall` batch file but couldn't find it in my Visual Studio installation directory. However, thanks to [this](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html) article, I found another way. Turns out that all I needed to do was to build from a *developer console*.

On my computer, I could start this dev console by going to `Start -> All Programs -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt for VS2015`. Alternatively, you can launch `VsDevCmd.bat`, located in `Common7\Tools\` directory of your Visual Studio installation.

And then everything worked! *Note that I did not need to bother with RubyInstaller or any of that jazz!*

Answer (score 0):

You want to compile it or install it? Because you don't need to compile it if you just want to install it. Check the binaries

http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: this website doesn't have the last version and i have read the readme win32 to install it manually using VC then this error show up

Comment: What version do you try to compile?

Answer (score 0):

**For downloading ruby**

I am not sure if you still need the answer, I also see that rubyinstaller does not have new ruby release also. After asking around for a while I found that they are posting new release at github. I downloaded 2.4.1 and it work for me.

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases

**For compiling ruby**

Please read this link so you will have info. they change to use msys2 and mingw now

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/